# Difference in Scala between abstracting class versus method

Tags: scala, generics

What's the difference in Scala between abstracting the class versus abstracting the method? When use one vs the other ?

```
class lookup[F[_]] {
  def searchUser(username: Username, email: Email): F[Option[User]]
}

object lookup {
  def searchUser[F[_]](username: Username, email: Email): F[Option[User]]
}
```

Comment: Usually, you would go for the first one _(although probably using a `trait`)_ and then provide some kind of factory method on the companion object that provides an implementation requiring some dependencies like `implicit ev:  Monad[F]` and / or something like `repository: Repository[F]` - This very useful to hide those constraints from users and free implementations, thus being able to create lightweight implementations for tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Semantics is different for these two cases.

In the first case `F` is resolved upon creating an instance of the class

```
class lookup[F[_]] {
  def searchUser(username: Username, email: Email): F[Option[User]] = ???
}

val l1 = new lookup[Future]
val l2 = new lookup[List]
l1.searchUser(username1, email1): Future[Option[User]]
l2.searchUser(username2, email2): List[Option[User]]
```

In the second case `F` is resolved upon method call

```
object lookup {
  def searchUser[F[_]](username: Username, email: Email): F[Option[User]] = ???
}

lookup.searchUser[Future](username1, email1): Future[Option[User]]
lookup.searchUser[List](username2, email2): List[Option[User]]
```

Suppose you will add one more method

```
class lookup[F[_]] {
  def searchUser(username: Username, email: Email): F[Option[User]] = ???
  def deleteUser(user: User): F[Unit] = ???
}
```

Here you know that `F` is the same for both methods. But for

```
object lookup {
  def searchUser[F[_]](username: Username, email: Email): F[Option[User]] = ???
  def deleteUser[F[_]](user: User): F[Unit] = ???
}
```

`F` in one method and `F` in another method can be different.

Also `lookup[F[_]]` can be used in implicits / type classes / context bounds (this is useful in [tagless final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tagless-final+scala) approach)

```
def foo[F[_]: lookup] = ???
def foo[F[_]](implicit l: lookup[F]) = ???
```

while in the second case you lose this ability.